# How to change color if value is negative with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with setting color if value is negative.

Please note that this class **p0** is added dynamically so it can be **p55** or any other number max is ***p100*** min is ***p0***. Also, value is added dynamically. So in this scenario where is p0 and number are negative(-0.75) I need to change color but only if a negative value is present, so my current code is like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pt = $('.p0 > span');
    var text = parseFloat($(pt).text().replace(',', '.'));    

    if (text < 0) {
        $(".p0").css({
            'background-color': '#32c787',
        })
    } else {
        ($('.p0')[0])
        $(".p0").css({
            'background-color': '#b7b4b4',
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle p0">
  <span>
         -0,75
      </span>
  <div class="slice">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="fill"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code is ok when the value is not negative. 
Can anybody help with this? I don't have an idea how to solve this. I update my JS code, so this is my approach.

Comment: store positive and negative value in `data-attr` and retrieve by `class`, based on that you can apply using jquery css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var pt = $('.p0 > span');
        var text = parseFloat($(pt).text().replace(',', '.'));    

        if (text < 0) {
            $(".p0").css({
                'background-color': '#32c787',
            })
        } else {
            ($('.p0')[0])
            $(".p0").css({
                'background-color': '#b7b4b4',
            })
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can loop over all the relevant div elements using their container as a reference, as you state the class name is not consistent, and then add the required class based on the value of the `span` it contains. Try this:

```js
$('#container > div').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.toggleClass('negative', parseFloat($el.find('span').text().replace(',', '.')) < 0);
});
```

```css
.negative {
  background-color: #b7b4b4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="circle p0">
    <span>-0,75</span>
  </div>
  <div class="circle p1">
    <span>1,95</span>
  </div>
  <div class="circle p2">
    <span>0,75</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the replacement of `,` with `.` before parsing the stirng to a float, as JS only supports `.` as the decimal point. Also, I removed the `.slice` elements as they are not relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check the value is positive or negative. Then change the background color of it.

Please try the below example -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var value = $(".circle span").html();
 if (value < 0) {
  $(".circle span").css({
    'background-color': '#b7b4b4',
  })
 }
});
```

[You can check the working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok123/jb25hkfm/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think if the values are dynamic and also the class name `p0` as you said, why don't you check the value is negative or positive at the time of placing it and then place another class accordingly like if the value is negative then add another class **negative-value** with **p0** or **p10** otherwise do not add extra class with **p0**.

It will save time and the code also.

add the CSS like,

```
.negative-value{
    background-color: #b7b4b4;
}
```